# Add multiple returns jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

how do I change the code below so that multiple elements with ids can be returned (actions to happen to more elements than just the one with id="firstId"). Thanks in advance.

```
   $("#main").change(function() {
    var first = $(this);
    $('#occupation').prop("disabled", function() {
        return first.children(":selected").attr("id") === ("firstId");
    });
});
```

Comment: I read this a few times and I'm still confused on what you're trying to do.  Could you provide more code and explanation here?

Comment: I'm assuming you want to send more than 1 thing back? You should use a JSON object and go through your returned values to set whatever actions you want to happen.

Comment: see this jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/FQrcG/. I want the second select to be disabled if anything apart from all or employed are selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var ids = ["firstId", "secondId"];
$("#main").change(function() {
    var first = $(this);
    $('#occupation').prop("disabled", function() {
        return jQuery.inArray(first.children(":selected").attr("id"), ids) !== -1;
    });
});
```

Comment: `inArray` will return the index or `-1` if not found. I think you could add `!== -1`.

Comment: curiosity: ~-1 === 0 therefore:
`return ~jQuery.inArray(first.children(":selected").attr("id"), ids);`

Comment: @jacktheripper it does work, I revised the answer just after you tested it http://jsfiddle.net/FQrcG/1/

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#employedSelect").change(function() {
    var wut = $(this).children(":selected").attr("id");
    $('#occupation').prop("disabled",((wut=="all")?false:(wut=="employed")?false:true));
});
```

Comment: I went by what your question was asking rather than what you were trying to do. Here is something that fits your needs http://jsfiddle.net/FQrcG/5/

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what you are expecting,

```
$("#employedSelect").change(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    var isPresent = false;
    $('#occupation').children("option").each(function(){
       if($(this).val() === value)
           isPresent = true;
    });
    if(isPresent )
      $('#occupation').attr("disabled","disabled");
    else
     $('#occupation').removeAttr("disabled");
});
```

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/FQrcG/4/